# vimscript - catching window resize automatically (with autocommand or not)

Tags: vim, window-resize, autocommand

So, I was trying to write an autocommand that would fire every time window is resized (not the Vim window entirely, a `CTRL-W` window).

As there is no dedicated event, i tried using `OptionSet` with different windows' sizes options, but that obviously does not work for `:resize` commands and keystrokes, etc.

I was thinking about catching `:resize` command itself, but it seems like there is no event for doing that (using events for entering a command line seems to be too expensive).

Are there any vim-fu masters who could show me the way? That would be great if there could be a universal way for catching window resizing per se, but other options would do too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The method I used [there](https://gist.github.com/romainl/047aca21e338df7ccf771f96858edb86) to perform different actions on `<CR>` depending on the current command-line could be used here, too:

```
function! MyCR()
    " grab the current command-line
    let cmdline = getcmdline()

    " does it start with 'resize'?
    if cmdline =~ '^resize'
        " press '<CR>' then do something with that information
        return "\<CR>:echo 'There was an attempt to resize the window.'"
    else
        " press '<CR>'
        return "\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction

" map '<CR>' in command-line mode to execute the function above
cnoremap <expr> <CR> MyCR()
```

Basically, when you press `<CR>` to execute an Ex command, do something specific when the command starts with `resize` and just do a normal `<CR>` otherwise.

Comment: This is indeed a clever solution I would never think of! The only problem that comes to mind is when some other person having a similar hacky mind tries to use my script (just imagining), things go boom.

Comment: Well, if you want to turn that thing into a plugin for others to use, you will certainly have to put at least *some* features behind options.

Comment: I  slept on this solution, and now it seems to me that this one and cmdlineleave event solution are in fact similar. The latter seems to be a bit more convenient for me as it will certainly not overwrite potential user's mappings, even though it doesn't cover all the potential events of windows resizing.

Comment: `CmdLineLeave` doesn't help because it is also triggered by `<Esc>` and `<C-c>`. As for the other ways of resizing windows, you could try to override the default commands like `<C-w>+`. Another option would be to poll the dimensions of each window with `:help timer` and `:help getwininfo()` and react accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, but sifting a needed command (say, "resize") in handler func would do the work (pretty much like in your example). Though, once again, it seems like it causes a big overhead to call the func every time only to check for one command.
Timer is a great option, thank you! But in my case i would need to set a timer to quite a small period. 

This is weird btw that VIm doesn't have a build in event, considering it clearly knows all windows' relevant dimensions at a given time.